# Как считать информацию с листа MS Word или Excel и внести изменения?

Tags: c#, c++, excel, api, ms-word

1. Необходимо считать информацию с листа `MS Word`, внести изменения.
2. Необходимо считать информацию с листа `MS Excel`, внести изменения.

Собственно вопросы - возможно сделать это с помощью каких-то библиотек для работы с `API MS Word, Excel`? Если да, то какие посоветуете? Подходит ли для этого `с++` вообще? Читал, что для таких целей подходит `MFC`, так же читал, что лучше всего подойдет `c#`.

Comment: По поводу шарпа и библиотек по работе с екселем я делал разбор вот здесь: 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-xlsx-csv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b/560134#560134  (читать нужно "Почему мой код написан именно так, а не иначе"). Собственно, по тому, что там написано сможешь выбрать что для тебя оптимальнее сам.

Comment: @ Andrew спасибо, почитаю

Comment: Для Excel вот есть пара примеров на С++: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/660695/240512 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/938498/240512

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight уж легче VB выучить-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем остановился на языке `c#` и библиотеке `docx` - это лучший вариант, всем советую, крайне удобно!

Answer (score 1):

Если вам необходимо именно заменить текст в шаблоне, то лучше всего подойдет Delphi а именно Embarcadero RAD Studio. Там есть встроенные библиотеки и решения. Если же вы хотите внедрить в свой проект на С#

```
    sing Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
        // Определение переменной oWord
    Word._Application oWord = new Word.Application();

        // 
    private void buttonDocument(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            // Считывает шаблон и сохраняет измененный в новом
        _Document oDoc = GetDoc(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Doc_propusk.dotx");
        oDoc.SaveAs(FileName: Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\For_print.docx");
        oDoc.Close();
    }

    private _Document GetDoc(string path)
    {
        _Document oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(path);
        SetTemplate(oDoc);
        return oDoc;
    }
        // Замена закладки SECONDNAME на данные введенные в textBox
    private void SetTemplate(Word._Document oDoc)
    {
        oDoc.Bookmarks["SECONDNAME"].Range.Text = textSecondName.Text;
             // если нужно заменять другие закладки, тогда копируем верхнюю строку изменяя на нужные параметры 
        
    }
```

Comment: Весьма плохое решение работать с екселем через интероп. Медленно просто до ужаса, должен быть установленный пакет офиса на компьютере с запускаемой программой и много утечек памяти и зависших невидимых процессов при каких-либо ошибках в написании кода. Советовать этот способ для работы с екселем - это издевательство над человеком. Это же касается и ворда.

Comment: Чтобы не было утечек объектов, см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/464115/184217

Comment: Спасибо, но делфи не интересен, у меня задача написать программу, в которой вводишь реквизиты организации и получаешь на выходе заполненный шаблон договора и спецификации, а в екселе интерес в общем поработать с ячейками и формулами, не применяя код VB.